# Use the same parameters many times in a find conditions: hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, dry

I have a model who holds 2 properties: valid_from and valid_to.

I need to select all instances that are currently valid, i.e. valid_from <= today and valid_to >= today.

i have the following find :

```
Mymodel.find(:all, :conditions => ["valid_from <= ? and valid_to >= ?", Date.today, Date.today])
```

I already thought about storing Date.today in a variable and calling that variable, but i still need to call it twice.

```
my_date = Date.today
Mymodel.find(:all, :conditions => ["valid_from <= ? and valid_to >= ?", my_date, my_date])
```

Is there a way to improve and do only one call to the variable to match all the "?" in the :conditions ?

thanks,
P.

Comment: Yea but the second snippet is more optimized as u don't need to do the calculation twice...

Comment: OK thanks, but is there a way to type only once "my_date" so that it matches both question marks in the conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `named_scope`. In model add:

```
named_scope :valid, 
            :conditions => 
             ["valid_from <= ? and valid_to >= ?", Date.today, Date.today]
```

And then in your controller you can call:

```
@mymodels = Mymodel.valid
```

I think that focusing on reducing two calls to Date.today to only one call is wasting of time. It won't make your application faster or using less memory.

Comment: i accept this answer for the last bit: there may be a way, but there is no point/particular benefit.
Thanks

Comment: The is a problem with using Date.today inside a named_scope. This is because the names scope is compiled when the activerecord model is first compiled. So, the call to Date.today is evaluated as this is a method call during the first time its found. On subsequent calls, this value will be fixed. So, its a good idea to take the value of the date as an input.
Read more about this known issue at http://jitu-blog.blogspot.com/2009/07/looking-into-rails-namedscope.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to do what you're asking, but even if you could I don't think it would buy you much. I would create a [named scope](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope) within your model class.

In this example, you can pass the date to the named scope, or it will default to today's date if no date is specified:

```
named_scope :by_valid_date, lambda { |*args|
            { :conditions => ["valid_from <= ? and valid_to >= ?",
              (args.first || Date.today), (args.first || Date.today)]} }
```